# SQL Server Log File Size

Tags: sql-server, database-backups, logfile

Apologies if this question was asked by someone.
I'm not much experienced in SQL server.

On our SQL server, there is 1 TB plus log file size.
Database is in full recovery.
Had taken an initial full backup and set a regular backup job for a transaction log for a stop to growing log file size too much.

so my question is, can I truncate my log file after taking log backup.

Comment: If your database is in full recovery mode, I personally would not suggest truncating (shrinking)it, at least not immediately. Are you actually performing **regular** transaction log backups? If not, time to start dong that, or do you *need* to have it in full, and would a simple recovery mode suffice? Either way, have you also considered setting a maximum size for your transaction log file?

Comment: A log backup truncates the log. However, it will not reduce the file size that may have grown large due to inattention. You can use `DBCC SHRINKFILE` for the log file to reduce the size but it still should be sized to accommodate modifications between log backups.

Comment: Thanks Larnu - Yes, its's already set as autogrowth. and we taken regular log  backup at end of day.

Answer (score 0):

If there was abnormal event like long running transaction or huge data import, you restore the previous size with the code below:

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE(2,TRUNCATEONLY);
ALTER DATABASE [StackOverflow] MODIFY FILE (NAME = N'StackOverflow_Log', SIZE = 256MB);
```

The `SHRINKFILE` second argument is the `file_id`:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.database_files;
```

Also, sometimes having a huge log file might be something normal. It basically depends on the activity on your database. So, `256 MB` might be more or less. It will be better to set a size, which will be enough for handling your normal workload without growing.

You should also check how often you are performing backup of the log file - each 10 minute or each 1 hour.